# Kitchen Faucet Low Water Pressure (Cold Only)

Tags: plumbing, faucet, water-pressure, kitchen-sink

Have a single handle kitchen faucet.  Hot water pressure works fine, but cold water has very low pressure (almost a trickle).

**Things I have tried:**

1. Cleaned the aerator (nothing blocking it)
2. Changed the cartridge (still same issue)
3. Verified the microscreens in the flex hose lines were not trapping any debris
4. Flushed both lines (unhooked hose from stop, removed microscreens, turned faucet on to mixed position in hopes something was clogging it... repeated for both hot and cold hoses.  No sediment or any debris)
5. Replaced the the entire fixture, repeated steps 1 through 4.  Same issue.
6. Called in a plumber - they said the issue was that the flex hose was in a loop and was causing the loss in pressure.  Not sure if this made too much sense to me since it seemed to be a gradual sweep (about a 4" diameter loop) and the loop was attached to the hot water stop (which has no issues with pressure).  Their recommendation was to get a new faucet with shorter lines...

**Temporary Fix**

Played around with it some more after the plumber left and noticed that I get my cold water pressure back for a limited time if I do the following:

1. Open the faucet to the cold water side (water trickles)
2. While the faucet is still open, I close the cold water valve under the sink completely
3. When I re-open the cold water valve, the cold water pressure is completely back to normal
4. This temp fix only lasts for maybe a couple hours at best and then it reverts back to a trickle

Short of going out and buying yet another faucet (with shorter lines apparently)... was wondering if anyone had any other ideas here.

**EDIT - RESOLUTION**
This was lodged behind the cold water shutoff valve.
[image]

Comment: Feels like you might have crud in the angle stop.

Comment: Think the problem might be at the shut off valve or further back in the pipe.  Is it only one faucet or others in the house?  If just that one then problem area should be limited from the shut off valve to where that line tees off the cold water line.  Think your plumber might not know that much, a kink in the hose yes, a soft loop no.

Comment: I agree with @crip659  that the shutoff valve could be the problem.  Try shutting off house water and remove the valve stem for the shutoff valve and flush it out.

Comment: @JACK  Think the problem might be before that valve from what OP says about turning it off, and then the pressure is normal for a bit after turning it back on.

Comment: @crip659  I was thinking that closing the valve dislodge something  that  reformed after it was opened.... and yes, could definitely be before the shutoff.

Comment: Photos of the cold water shutoff valve would help - if it's a multi-turn valve, JACK's idea about the valve getting clogged makes a lot of sense, and is fairly straightforward to DIY fix. The rubber washer inside the multi-turn shutoff valve breaks down over time and the pieces often cause flow issues.

Comment: Appreciate the responses all!  Issue resolved- took off the cold water stop valve and out popped a giant (what looks to be) board game piece to Sorry.  Hooked it all back up and pressure is back to normal.  Guess the thought never occurred to me that a giant blockage would be behind the stop.   For completeness sake, this was the only fixture in the house that had the low water pressure.

Comment: Now just tell us how did that get in there

Comment: Would make a new question with that picture(maybe more) asking if any plumbing person could recognize that part.  Does not seem a normal piece to find inside of pipes.  Pipes are not places where dropped pieces go.  It might be from a check valve/pressure regulator.

Comment: @crip659 - good idea.  I'll link to the other question here as well.  Thanks again for everyone's help!  https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/252390/plumbing-piece-identification-from-stop-valve-removal