# Plumbing Piece(?) Identification From Stop Valve Removal

Tags: plumbing, valve, kitchen-sink

Posted a question here to help me debug low water pressure to my kitchen faucet.  Link to post here:

[kitchen-faucet-low-water-pressure-cold-only](https://diy.stackexcha)

Basically, there was low water pressure only on the cold side of the faucet.  The cold water stop valve was removed and this piece popped out which was clogging the flow to my faucet flex hose.  While my pressure is now back to normal, just wanted to make sure this doesn't belong to something else that will cause other issues in the future-  (that number `6` or `9` is the only printing on the component)

Any help would be appreciated!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wonder if your plumber played golf?

Comment: Seeing the pipe joints(elbows/tees) that piece looks too large to make the bends, so it must have been placed in the straight section of the pipe before the valve.  It could be from somewhere else.  Somebody is playing tricks on you.

Comment: Perhaps part of a check valve or backflow preventer.

Comment: @Armand  Thought maybe the same with the link question, but seeing the joints and the size think it is almost impossible to make the those bends.

Comment: My guess is that it's a backflow preventer.